# Reaching Maximum Recursion Depth while Using Dask and Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, dask, large-data

I'm using the pytorch dataloader. What I am doing is inputting an array of temperatures from an hdf5 file, then I want to leverage the num_workers of the dataloader in order to do some manipulation on the temperature data before returning it in get_item. So essentially, the class has data that is accessed by y, x, year and each of these combinations contains an array. I'm using A LOT of data, so I'm using dask to not load everything into memory at once. I want to get out a hdf5 file in the form of [y, x, year, band, day] where band {0, 1} where 0 is the modified temperature and 1 is the date of the temperature reading. Day is used to specify the value of that day of the reading.

When I save the dask file to hdf5, I get a recursion error of the form

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I've tried modifying temperature_array to a dask array, moving some compute calls around, changing batch size, etc. (I've tried others stuff for related problems but it may be too confusing if I lay this all out)

UPDATE: I solved this issue with `sys.setrecursionlimit(3000)  # Set recursion limit to a higher value` but I don't think this will work for my much larger dataset, so I'm looking for alternative solutions!

```
class TemperatureDataset(Dataset):
    '''
    Creates accumulated degree day timeseries for the specified base.

    Requires some sort of temperature related data to accumulate, and the dates of each image accordingly.
    '''
.
.
.

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        #get a year and a point, and then accumulate the data for that point


        temperature_file = h5py.File(self.temperature_path, 'r')
        temperature_data = da.from_array(temperature_file['/data'])
        

        date_file = h5py.File(self.date_path, 'r')
        dates = date_file['images_date'][:].astype(str)

        
        #changing indexing to fit multidimensional array
        shape_of_array = (len(temperature_data[0,:,0]), len(temperature_data[0,0,:]), number_of_years) 
        
        index = np.unravel_index(idx, shape_of_array)

        y = index[0]
        x = index[1]
        year = int(index[2] + 2001)

        

        acc_temperature = []
        start = 0
        # loop through the days until you get to the right year
        for i in range(len(temperature_data[:,0,0])):
            if int(dates[i][:4]) < year:
                continue
            if int(dates[i][:4]) == year:
                # save starting index then accumulate temperatures for that year and point
                start = i
                # NOTE: CALLING COMPUTE HERE ON SUBSET OF DATA
                
                acc_temperature = np.cumsum(temperature_data[i:(i + self.T), index[0], index[1]].compute())
                
                break

       #feel free to ignore what the dates represent. It's not part of the problem
        date_int_list = []
        # Convert the date string to a datetime object that can be stored in the return tensor
        for i in range(start, start + NUMBER_OF_DATA_DAYS):
            datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(dates[i], '%Y-%m-%d')
            date_int = int(datetime_obj.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
            date_int_list.append(date_int)

        # returns 
        return acc_temperature, torch.tensor(date_int_list), index[0], index[1], year

    
   


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = TemperatureDataset(path_to_temperature_data, path_to_dates)
    dataloader = DataLoader(data, batch_size = batch_size, shuffle = False, num_workers = num_workers)

    temperature_file = h5py.File(path_to_temperature_data, 'r')
    temperature_data = da.from_array(temperature_file['/data'])

    # number_of_tuples = number_of_years * len(temperature_data[:,0,0]) * len(temperature_data[:,0,0])


    #loading data into a dask array and storing it to hdf5 to create a file of accumulated temperatures for that base
    loaded_data = da.empty(shape=(len(temperature_data[0,:,0]), len(temperature_data[0,0,:]), number_of_years, 2, NUMBER_OF_DATA_DAYS), dtype = np.float32)
    # print(loaded_data.shape)
    for batch in tqdm(dataloader):
        # print(batch)
        for i in range(batch_size):
            if i >= len(batch[0]):
                break
            temperature_array = da.from_array(batch[0][i].numpy())
            dates = batch[1][i].numpy()
            y = int(batch[2][i])
            x = int(batch[3][i])
            year = int(batch[4][i] - 2001)

            # print(f'{y} {x}')



            # TODO: May want to remove year from this to reduce dimensionality and duplication? but perhaps compression takes care of it
            loaded_data[y, x, year, 0, :] = temperature_array
            loaded_data[y, x, year, 1, :] = dates


    
    progress_bar = ProgressBar()
    with progress_bar:
        da.to_hdf5(f'accumulated_degree_day_data_per_x_y_year_base_{base}.hdf5', {'/data': loaded_data})
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, since the code you provided is large and we also unable to reproduce. Here you can help minimizing the line of code, pointing which line getting recursion error and we can help you better.

Comment: Thank you for the tip: The error occurs when the line ```da.to_hdf5(f'accumulated...``` is executed. Perhaps there are too many dask operations called at the same time at that point?